# a Regex to filter an arithmetic expression, prevent multiple consecutive symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, filter

I have an arithmetic expression, it might have multiple consecutive signs (1++2-3) this would create an error in the "eval()" function, i want to remove only the extra repetitions of the sign and keep only one

i created this regex: /[+-/*]{2,}/g
the problem is it captures all the repetitions, so i end up removing the sign all together

```
let eq = '1+++2-2'
let regex = /[+-/*]{2,}/g
```

Comment: What should happen to `1+/+2-2` or `1+-2-2`? The second example is a valid JS expression.

Comment: What you have to understand is that all arithmetic is _addition_. There is no subtraction in arithmetic. So `2-8` is really `2 + -8`, where the _OPERATOR_ is always the `+` and the sign is always either `-` or nothing.

Comment: I am trying to create a simple calculator app, so it behaves exactly like a regular calculator, so if i press like (1+/-1) i get (1-1), only the last sign is considered correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let eq = "1+++2-2";
let result = eq.replace(/([+-/*]){2,}/g, "$1");

console.log(result);

// 1+2-2
```

Comment: yes, here we capture the single char "before" pluralization.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I am grateful for the time you spent to answer my question, I would also like to ask if you can up-vote my question.